# lightdm: cannot type password on login screen

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, unity-greeter

I am running 12.04 LTS, fully updated. My system is configured to automatically log me in into my account. Auto-login works fine.

However, sometimes I need to access the unity-greeter/lightdm login screen. For example, this happens when I log out and then want another user want to log into their account. The interface we get is exactly the one shown on [the Wikipedia page for LightDM](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/LightDM_1.2.1_on_Ubuntu_12.04.png/800px-LightDM_1.2.1_on_Ubuntu_12.04.png):

- the password prompt is grayed out and I am unable to type my password
- the mouse moves fine but I cannot click the system icons on the
  top-right corner of the menu bar does not work
- I can switch using ctrl-alt-f? to a console and login fine using the text/console login prompt. If I kill X, I am again returned to the same unusable login screen.

How can I fix this? How can a user log into their graphical environment without having to reboot the system?

Comment: Does anything change if you click on your user name?

Comment: You can try to [debug lightdm](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Debugging_LightDM) or you [switch back to GDM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#What_to_do_if_things_go_wrong)

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered the same on random occasions on my 14.04 LTS installation. I have not been able to reproduce it. Sometimes it just happens and I am stuck at login.

I have added this alias to to my `.bash_aliases` file as a workaround that have worked so far:

```
alias saveme="export XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0 && dm-tool switch-to-greeter && logout"
```

When login prompt is grayed out. I switch to e.g. tty1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login and just enter my alias: `saveme`.

This way you will not lose any work from open applications. When you restart lightdm you will lose everything you had running which was really annoying and something I wanted to avoid..

`XDG_SEAT_PATH` may not be the same for you. Check while logged in in a terminal:

```
env | grep -i XDG_SEAT_PATH
```

You can also check with:

```
dm-tool list-seats
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug is still present in 16.10.   I usually ssh from another machine, kill the gnome-screensaver process and that returns me to my session.  No need to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to disable lock screen under power management and install `xscreensaver` and configure screen login from there

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to uninstall the xscreensaver packages.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [bug reported at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1311316).

The bug has been fixed in an updated version of Unity: 7.2.4+14.04.20141217-0ubuntu1. This fix should be included in 15.04 release as well.

Comment: this bug is still in 20.04 and seems to be related to lightdm & screensaver.